# Lastlogon time on DC return different value in .Net and powershell

Tags: c#, powershell, active-directory, domaincontroller

I'm writing a little application that can audit the lastlogon time of a user on every DC in our environment. 
With a little help I was able to create a code that iterate all the DC's and query the lastlogon time of a user. As I read it before this value isn't synchronizing among the DC's and this is a by design by MS.
Here is the code I use to check a user on every DC:

```
        foreach (string DCInstance in DC_Collection)
        {
            try
            {
                using (PrincipalContext context = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain,DCInstance))
                {
                    using (UserPrincipal userPrincipal = new UserPrincipal(context))
                    {                            
                        userPrincipal.Name = "TestUserName";

                        using (PrincipalSearcher searcher = new PrincipalSearcher(userPrincipal))
                        {

                            using (PrincipalSearchResult<Principal> results = searcher.FindAll())
                            {
                                foreach (UserPrincipal FoundUser in results)
                                {
                                    Console.WriteLine(FoundUser.SamAccountName + "," + FoundUser.LastLogon + "," + DCInstance);

                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            catch (PrincipalServerDownException PSDE)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(PSDE.Message + ": " + DCInstance);
            }
        }
```

I know that many of the brackets are unnecessary but it is just more readable to me this way.

This is the core of the program. However I recognized that the lastlogon time of the found user is the same on each DC instance, which is quite unlikely.
To make sure of this issue I made a little PS script that do the same thing, so I can compare the results. Here is the PS script:

```
foreach($dc in $dcs)
 { 
   $hostname = $dc.HostName
   $user = Get-ADUser $userName -Server $hostname | Get-ADObject -Properties lastLogon
}
```

Again this is only the core of the script that make the actual work.

The result however are completely differs. The PS script results the the times as I expected, quite different on almost every DC (not all differs from the others but most of them). The .Net program however returns the same time from all DC instances and in addition it returns a time that do not displays in the PS script!

Now I'm quite confused. I believe the PS script is the correct one, but then I really do not know what did I missed in the .Net version.

I did some debug on the program but the found user contains only the time that the program displays, and even the filetime value different from the PS version.
I even thought on date-time conversion issue, but then the structure of the result should be the same with different values, but they aren't.

Thx in advance for any sort of help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer! :-)

I modified the C# code to return the filetime on the assumed Last logon data, and also did a detailed ps script to list every variable of the user so I can find the relevant property returned by the c#.

Here is a PS script:

```
Get-ADUser TestUser | Get-ADObject -Properties *
```

This line returns every property that is stored in the AD about the given user.
Among others there are two value I care about:

**lastLogon** and **lastLogonTimestamp**

After this I checked the filetime version of the **lastlogon** property returned by the c# and it turened out, that this value is actually the same with the **lastLogonTimestamp** and there is no (or I did not found) way to request the exact **lastlogon** data.

The proper solution is to redesign the code the operate with LDAP queries instead of API calls. 
Little help for that can be found [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/19181/Find-LastLogon-Across-All-Windows-Domain-Controlle)